# Azure Multi Factor Authentication Mobile App Error

Tags: azure, authentication, multi-factor-authentication

I am trying to configure MFA using Azure MFA. Its all working correctly apart from getting the following error in the Mobile App when scanning a QR code (adding manually produces the same error):

[image]

The web service looks to be configured correctly:
https://mfa.optimisemedia.com/MultiFactorAuthMobileAppWebService/pfpaws.asmx

And the Web Service SDK:
https://mfa.optimisemedia.com/MultiFactorAuthWebServiceSdk/

Any help greatly appreciated as I've come up against a brick wall now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the problem was down to IIS permissions. The installer doesn't set these correctly.

More info can be found at  https://dirteam.com/sander/2015/03/27/knowledgebase-you-receive-a-web-service-requests-must-be-protected-by-authentication-error-when-activating-a-multi-factor-auth-app/